# Is this a Symmetric Matrix or not?

Tags: matrix, numerics, probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra

I've generated the `cov` matrix in the following way:

```
kernel[x1_, x2_] := Exp[-1/2*Norm[x1 - x2]^2];
Xtest = Range[-5, 5, 2];
n = Length[Xtest];
Xtrain = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 5];
kmat[x1_, x2_] := Module[{mat},
   n = Length[x1];
   n2 = Length[x2];
   mat = ConstantArray[0, {n, n2}];
   For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
    For[j = 1, j <= n2, j++,
      mat[[i, j]] = kernel[x1[[i]], x2[[j]]];
      ];
    ];
   mat
   ];

m = kmat[Xtest, Xtrain] // N[#, {Infinity, 1000}] &;

mean = (m.Inverse[kmat[Xtrain, Xtrain]].fobs) // 
   N[#, {Infinity, 1000}] &;
cov = (kmat[Xtest, Xtest] - 
     m.Inverse[kmat[Xtrain, Xtrain]].Transpose[m]) // 
   N[#, {Infinity, 1000}] &;
```

Theoretically, `cov` should be symmetric. However, when I do `SymmetricMatrixQ[cov]`, it returns `False`.
It's the `m.Inverse[kmat[Xtrain, Xtrain]].Transpose[m]` which returns a non-symmetric matrix when it should not. When I do `SymmetricMatrixQ[Inverse[kmat[Xtrain, Xtrain]]]` I get True.

My objective is to be able to run `RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[mean, cov], 4];` which I can't, since *Mathematica* thinks it's not symmetric or PD...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Something to note, `SymmetricMatrixQ[cov, Tolerance -> 10^-12]` returns `False`, while `SymmetricMatrixQ[cov, Tolerance -> 10^-11]` returns `True`.

Comment: Evaluate this to see which values trigger the `False`: `Table[{i, j, cov[[i, j]] == Transpose[cov][[i, j]]}, {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}]`. I'll leave it up to you to sort out how that happened. In playing with this, a handful of times I have gotten a `cov` that `SymmetricMatrixQ` returned `True` for.

Comment: @user6014 Thanks for the comments. I've checked and the values indeed differ, when they should not. Why isn't enough to just use N[,{infinity, big number}]?

Comment: I don't think this tells the whole story, but applying your `N` statement retroactively doesn't fix precision discrepancies/losses that happened in the earlier `(kmat[Xtest, Xtest] - m.Inverse[kmat[Xtrain, Xtrain]].Transpose[m])` computation. I'd have to really sit down and look at it to see if that's actually what's going on here, though.

Comment: @user6014 If you could look at it, I would really appreciate it. I have no idea how to proceed forward from here. I've even tried to write the kmat function with the N infinity command...

Comment: It is symmetric to within small numeric roundoff, and the `Tolerance` option will allow one to check this.. `In[368]:= SymmetricMatrixQ[cov, Tolerance -> 10^(-9)]

Out[368]= True` At setting `10^(-10)` it will return `False` because `(cov - Transpose[cov])/Abs[cov]` has one value exceeding that threshold.

Comment: ...you noticed that `Xtrain = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 5]` generates its results in machine precision, didn't you? (Look up the `WorkingPrecision` option.) Also, consider using `DistanceMatrix[]` and `LinearSolve[]`: `m = Exp[-DistanceMatrix[Xtest, Xtrain]^2/2]; lsf = LinearSolve[Exp[-DistanceMatrix[Xtrain]^2/2]]; mean = m.lsf[fobs]; cov = Exp[-DistanceMatrix[Xtest]^2/2] - m.lsf[Transpose[m]];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I do in that situmation (which comes up quite often):

```
cov = .5 * (cov + Transpose[cov]);
```

Comment: very nice! many thanks;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see if a matrix `a` is symmetric, subtract it from its transpose, and see if it's zero:

```
a - Transpose[a] // Norm
```

or

```
a - Transpose[a] // Max
```

depending on how you want to measure the "distance away from symmetry".

So for `a = {{1, 2}, {2, 3}}` you will get zero, for `a = {{1, 2}, {2.0001, 3}}`, you will get a small number. This is what is probably happening in your construction, some element(s) `i,j` are just slightly different from the corresponding `j,i` element.

Comment: Note: `a - Transpose[a] // Abs // Max` is not required as `a - Transpose[a]` is a skew-symmetric matrix, so `Abs` would not change anything.