# Failure in MultinormalDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

My `RandomVariate` fails to evaluate when sampling from a multinormal distribution, any idea what's happening here?

This is Mathematica 12.1 on Mac:

```
d = 6;
sigma = {{0.2456589529728737`, 0.06467112508291382`, 
    0.07381608109139866`, 0.01761648518373636`, 0.05925859721052876`, 
    0.045898960400932734`}, {0.06467112508291387`, 
    0.35501955566599797`, 
    0.05242856376555134`, -0.009970312195220573`, 
    0.015359942596352098`, 
    0.02448314785173377`}, {0.07381608109139871`, 
    0.05242856376555134`, 0.3026715722222353`, -0.0819524814567561`, 
    0.07919970253622352`, -0.033627335100296744`}, \
{0.01761648518373638`, -0.009970312195220557`, -0.08195248145675606`, 
    0.5519153257149109`, -0.1068423071796184`, 
    0.35028088018797104`}, {0.05925859721052879`, 
    0.015359942596352072`, 
    0.07919970253622348`, -0.10684230717961839`, 0.29853333010040306`,
     0.002543954098042138`}, {0.0458989604009327`, 
    0.02448314785173373`, -0.033627335100296814`, 
    0.35028088018797104`, 0.002543954098042013`, 0.6962012633235793`}};
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[sigma] (* fails *)
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[sigma + ii] (* works *)
```

The example above was generated by code below, it's a random covariance matrix with geometrically decaying eigenvalues, so not even that close to singular --

````
randomRotation[n_] := Module[{M, z, q, r, d, ph},
   z = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {n, n}];
   {q, r} = QRDecomposition[z];
   d = Diagonal[r];
   ph = d/Abs[d];
   M = q*ph; (* Note, determinant may be -1 giving "pseudo-rotation", 
   switch 2 rows of the matrix to guarantee true rotation *)
   indices = If[Det[M] > 0, Range[n], {2, 1}~Join~Range[3, n]];
   M[[indices]]
   ];

d = 20;
rot = randomRotation[d];
ii = IdentityMatrix[d];

sigma = rot.DiagonalMatrix[Table[1/i, {i, 1, d}]].Inverse[rot];
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[sigma] (* fails *)
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[sigma+ii] (* works *)
```
````

Comment: "...symmetric positive definite..." for the covariance. Sigma does not meet the condition. That said, an error should be for that, instead it seems to fail in the definition of the distribution itself (that is, `MultinormalDistribution[sigma]` should note the condition failure).

You could try something like `RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[N[Rationalize[sigma, 0], 8]]`

Comment: ah, thanks...it looks like symmetry failure from numerical noise. On Mac the error was not very informative, it just said `MultinormalDistribution called with 1 argument; 2 arguments expected`

Comment: For whatever it's worth on Windows one gets the same 1 vs 2 arguments error.  Also, see the answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152987/is-this-a-symmetric-matrix-or-not which gives a function to force the approximately symmetric matrix to be symmetric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just got stumped by this error again in 13.1. Something inside `MultinormalDistribution` checks sigma for symmetry without tolerance for numerical noise.

Solution is to manually symmetrize the covariance like this `MultinormalDistribution[1/2(sigma+Transpose@sigma)]`

Repro:

```
d = 6;
sigma = {{0.2456589529728737`, 0.06467112508291382`, 
    0.07381608109139866`, 0.01761648518373636`, 0.05925859721052876`, 
    0.045898960400932734`}, {0.06467112508291387`, 
    0.35501955566599797`, 
    0.05242856376555134`, -0.009970312195220573`, 
    0.015359942596352098`, 
    0.02448314785173377`}, {0.07381608109139871`, 
    0.05242856376555134`, 0.3026715722222353`, -0.0819524814567561`, 
    0.07919970253622352`, -0.033627335100296744`}, \
{0.01761648518373638`, -0.009970312195220557`, -0.08195248145675606`, 
    0.5519153257149109`, -0.1068423071796184`, 
    0.35028088018797104`}, {0.05925859721052879`, 
    0.015359942596352072`, 
    0.07919970253622348`, -0.10684230717961839`, 0.29853333010040306`,
     0.002543954098042138`}, {0.0458989604009327`, 
    0.02448314785173373`, -0.033627335100296814`, 
    0.35028088018797104`, 0.002543954098042013`, 0.6962012633235793`}};
PositiveDefiniteMatrixQ[sigma] (* True *)
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[sigma] (* Fails "MultinormalDistribution called with 1 argument; 2 arguments are expected" *)
RandomVariate@MultinormalDistribution[1/2(sigma+Transpose@sigma)] (* Works *)
```